# What is the difference between probe and scan?

Tags: network, nmap

I'm struggling to understand the difference between probe and scan because they seem very similar. Does NMAP tool use probes and scans?

Could you give a practical example to make the theoretical difference more clear?

Comment: Its totally the same thing. Probing and scanning are the same thing in context of security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A scan generally means you are using the tools of a system to return precise information about it.  A probe means that you are testing inputs into a system to make educated guesses about it based on it's output.

For example, if you want to know if a website is WordPress, the admin could use the server's file manager to do a scan for files commonly associated with WordPress.  An end user who lacks that privilege may probe your site by testing to see if the site has a login page at ./wp-admin.